# Set repository for XCode project

Tags: xcode, svn, repository

I accidentally deleted the repository in the XCode Organizer. I've set up the repository again but how can I tell the project which one it should use because I get this error:

> The repository "(null)" could not be reached.

I think it was a little bit easier in Xcode 3.

Comment: I've solved it by checking it out again and overwrite the files. Then I could commit the files again. Maybe there is another, better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After setting it up again by using "Add working copy..." from the Repository-Tab in the Organizer - restart Xcode4. This worked for me a minute ago with Xcode 4.2

Comment: As a sidenote: I now stopped using git from within Xcode and changed my workflow to use an external git client. Maybe you want to do the same. I am using Sourcetree, but Tower looks good, too.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your svn project from the command line and remove all .git folders. Then re-check in the project. Once this is done you should be able to checkout the svn project via Xcode's opening splash screen and it should behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this before.  Xcode and svn don't work terribly nicely all the time.

My solution to fixing Xcode/svn issues that I've had usually involves firstly backing up any changed files, then removing the repository from Xcode, and deleting the working project folder, then re-adding the repository and checking out the project folder again.  This give me a clean working copy.  At this point then I need to go and manually re-edit any files that I've made changes in from the backups.

It's not the fastest method of fixing these issues, but at least I understand the solution, and can do it fairly easily.

In the case where I've gotten the "the repository (null) could not be reached" error after doing this, I found that actually restarting Xcode made the problem go away.